# Ребят, нужно приконектить java к postgresql. Постоянно ошибка Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, postgresql

Скачала драйвер. Оставила в одной папке с моим файлом java на диске C. Какую команду не использую, постоянно ошибка Could not find or load main class labo.java
Пробовала так:
java -cp ./postgresql-42.2.18.jar labo.java
java -cp c:\postgresql-42.2.18.jar labo.java

[image: мой код]

Comment: судя по описанию проблемы, вам базу данных подключать не нужно, а очень необходимо подучить самые азы. если набить в гугле уроки java, то подойдет практически любой курс лекций

Comment: Спасибо! Я попробовала, но к сожалению, ошибка осталась

Comment: @Вероника если проблема еще актуальна, могу предложить попробовать синтаксис, который используется в этих ответах: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt/9395928